# Apache Thrift and Android: TTransportException

Tags: java, php, android, apache, thrift

The problem with Apache Thrift work in android.

I am using Apache Thrift.
There is a PHP server.
There is a client for Java ( Simple Java project).
Everything is working.

When I create a client on Android, the connection to the server is successful. The functions are processed on the server, but in the application I get the error :

```
TTransportException: No more data available.
```

Transport - http.
Protocol - binary.

Code to create a client (and the same in a simple java project and android project):

```
TTransport transport = new THttpClient ("http://test.../PhpServer.php");
TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol (transport);
TestService.Client client = new TestService.Client (protocol);
transport.open ();
try {
    client.EchoI32 (4);
} Catch (SysException e) {
    e.printStackTrace ();
} Catch (TException e) {
    e.printStackTrace ();
}
```

LogCat:

```
09-09 14:43:07.107: W/System.err(31729): org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: No more data available.
09-09 14:43:07.107: W/System.err(31729):  at org.apache.thrift.transport.THttpClient.read(THttpClient.java:190)
09-09 14:43:07.107: W/System.err(31729):  at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
09-09 14:43:07.107: W/System.err(31729):  at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:359)
09-09 14:43:07.107: W/System.err(31729):  at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:278)
09-09 14:43:07.107: W/System.err(31729):  at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:185)
09-09 14:43:07.107: W/System.err(31729):  at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
09-09 14:43:07.107: W/System.err(31729):  at com.test.protocol.TestService$Client.recv_EchoI32(TestService.java:912)
```

Comment: It coulds be worth a try asking this in the Thrift users' mailing list.

Comment: I decided it. In android problem with data compression. Frpm Android in title to server sends Accept-Encoding: gzip. Server, of course, shaking. A THttpClient does not understand that he was sent. Moreover, it is only on android. That this class is to blame org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost. Can be rewritten THttpClient. Either ignore server Accept-Encoding: gzip.